# Pasar más de un parámetro - Ajax XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

¿Cómo sería la sintaxis para pasar más de un parámetro en está petición Ajax?

```
miXHR.open(
          "GET",
          "../servidor/autobuses.php?origen="+origen+"destino="+destino;
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta poner "&" entre cada parámetro. Así podrás pasar varios parámetros en el querystring:

```
"../servidor/autobuses.php?origen="+origen+"&destino="+destino;
```

Comment: No sabía como hacerlo, funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias!